# Mapper and Reducer programs for the predictions in python

Tags: python, hadoop

I have a confusion about the implementation of Hadoop. i have wriiten the code for the predicting the class values.Here's my code to build the decision tree and to predict the values

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import os

import random

from sklearn import tree

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

os.chdir('/home/PYTHON/')
data=pd.read_csv('wine.csv')


test_score=[]
error1=[]
error2=[]
accuracy=[]

n_fold=10

for i in xrange(n_fold):

    train_data = data.sample(frac=0.70,random_state=1)

    test_data = data.loc[~data.index.isin(train_data.index)]    

    tree_model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    predictors = train_data.ix[:,0:13]

    train_y = train_data.ix[:,13]

    model=tree_model.fit(X = predictors, y = train_y)

    test_feat = test_data.ix[:,0:13]

    test_y = test_data.ix[:,13]

    #Finding the class value of each row and the accuracy

    test_preds = model.predict(X=test_feat)

    test_score.append(i)

    test_score[i] = accuracy_score(test_y, test_preds)

print("Accuracy by acc_score", sum(accuracy)/len(accuracy))
```

I am beginner to both python and hadoop. I don't know how to divide this program as mapper and reducer. I am using hadoop-2.7.3 only with 3 data nodes. can I implement this program in hadoop cluster to predict the class values and finding accuracy? In case not how would the mapper and reducer be like for predicting the class and finding accuracy?

Comment: I have no experience with hadoop, but the benefit of using hadoop is the ability to scale when processing large datasets. How much data do you plan on processing for this project? Also, map reduce is a design pattern, and I don't think it needs to be implemented for every problem. The mapping part is taking some data and transforming it to some form that is useful to you. The reduce part can be doing a couple different things. One simple example of reducing some mapped data is just to count the occurrences of a piece of data. So you are "reducing" all of the occurrences to one number: a count.

Comment: I'd executed word count problem using python and I'd gone through what is hadoop and mapreduce. But I am doing this as academic project with the objective of parallel implementation. currently I planned to use about 5 millions lines of data or more.